# awk: Adding a new column based on concatenated value of two columns

Tags: awk

I am trying to add a new column to a text file based on the concatenated values of two columns.  Value is being inserted in the middle instead of the end of the string.

I am using awk.  Here are two sample lines

```
$ head -1 file.txt

8502CC169154|02|GA|TN|89840|9|2008-11-15 00:00:00.000|2009-11-15 00:00:00.000|1|TEAM1|1639009|1000000|0|2008-11-15 00:00:00.000|2009-11-15 00:00:00.000|85|00|37421||241|20|331|1052A|5000|0|.1500|Chattanooga|47065|.000|025|35|25000|0|0|0|0|0|718||E|-17.00|-17.00|-17.00|-17.00|-17.00|-2.55|-2.55|-2.55|-2.55|D|C9N7I4115531902|-2.19|-2.19|-2.19|-2.19|-14.81|051|2008-12-31 00:00:00.000|151|2008-12-17 00:00:00.000|||AC|CC|Y||2008-12-31 00:00:00.000|.000000|A|.000000|.000000|.000000|Y|8502CC169154-8|8502CC169154|8|||122130|122130M|7764298|RA
```

I tried the following.

```
$ head -1 file.txt | awk -F'|' '{$(NF+1)=$1"-"$6;}1' OFS='|'
```

I am expecting a new column at the end of the string.  But you can see that the concatenated field is being inserted in the middle of the string instead of the end of the string.

```
8502CC169154|02|GA|TN|89840|9|2008-11-15 00:00:00.000|2009-11-15 00:00:00.000|1|TEAM1|1639009|1000000|0|2008-11-15 00:00:00.000|2009-11-15 00:00:00.000|85|00|37421||241|20|331|1052A|5000|0|.1500|Chattanooga|47065|.000|025|35|25000|0|0|0|0|0|718||E|-17.00|-17.00|-17.00|-17.00|-17.00|-2.55|-2.55|-2.55|-2.55|D|C9N7I4115531902|-2.19|-2.19|-2.19|-2.19|-14.81|051|2008-12-31 00:00:00.000|151|2008|8502CC169154-9.000|||AC|CC|Y||2008-12-31 00:00:00.000|.000000|A|.000000|.000000|.000000|Y|8502CC169154-8|8502CC169154|8|||122130|122130M|7764298|RA
```

Comment: It works for me with GNU awk.  What is your OS and what is the output of `awk --version` on your system?

Comment: Try: `head -1 file.txt | awk -F'|' '{$0=$0 FS $1"-"$6;}1' OFS='|'`

Comment: For greater efficiency: `awk -F'|' '{print $0 FS $1"-"$6;exit}' file.txt`

Comment: @John1024 - that looks suspiciously close to an answer... Care to do the honors?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Very good.  Answer created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code works for me using GNU awk but I suspect that not all awks support setting `$(NF+1)`.  To avoid that, try:

```
head -1 file.txt | awk -F'|' '{$0=$0 FS $1"-"$6;}1' OFS='|'
```

Awk is a surprising powerful language and it has all the capabilities that `head` has, making the pipeline unnecessary.  So, for greater efficiency, try the simple command:

```
awk -F'|' '{print $0 FS $1"-"$6; exit}' file.txt
```

How it works:

- `-F'|'`

  This sets the field separator to a vertical bar.
- `print $0 FS $1"-"$6`

  This prints the output line that you want which consists of the original line, `$0`, followed by a field separator, `FS`, followed by combination of the first field, a dash, and the sixth field.
- `exit`

  After the first line is printed, this tells awk to exit.  This eliminates the need for `head -1`.